# Change the popover location dynamically while resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using Twitter Bootstrap popover and I don't know how would be able to change the popover location dinamic while resizing browser window. The problem is that when i resize the window, popover stays fixed on position. I want to delay the popover like other html elements.

Code:

```
$('#popover1').popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return $("#form").html();
    },
    placement: "top"
});
```

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function() { /* reposition popover here */ });`

Comment: Solution : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3117

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.  It calls the `show` event for all visible popovers:

```
$(window).off("resize").on("resize", function() {
    $(".popover").each(function() {
        var popover = $(this);
        if (popover.is(":visible")) {
            var ctrl = $(popover.context);
            ctrl.popover('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I know this is kinda late, but I'm having the same problem atm. This answers works for me as well. However, when I set the popover placement to left or right, it doesn't re-position the popover correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following questions and answers:

- [Bootstrap Popover showing at wrong place upon zoom in/out or resizing Browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638831/bootstrap-popover-showing-at-wrong-place-upon-zoom-in-out-or-resizing-browser-wi)
- [jQuery position element based on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539856/jquery-position-element-based-on-window-resize)

You need to use an event handler for the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // your positioning code here
});
```

Within this code you must reposition your element.